# Should I be installing node modules globally?

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm, gulp, zurb-foundation

I have gotten better at using the command line. I now use it regularly for foundation, gulp, ionic, etc. One thing I always struggle with is should I be installing modules globally?

I just got a new computer and I am starting fresh. When I do my first Foundation Project, or set up Gulp, when it prompts me to run 'npm install' should I be installing that gloabally? And if I do, will I need to run npm install the next time I set up a Foundation Project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that NPMs documentation really sums it up quite nicely:

> If you want to use it as a command line tool, something like the grunt CLI, then you want to install it globally. On the other hand, if you want to depend on the package from your own module using something like Node's require, then you want to install locally.

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally

In this case, you should install locally since they are dependencies of the application and not general command line utilities.

Comment: Thanks.. I read this several times before posting questions. For some reason the sentence at the end made more sense to me.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn’t fit the Q&A format too well, but I would in general advise against that. Installing modules globally may lead to side effects in other projects that depend on the same packages.

I don’t know what a “Foundation Project” is (and Google does not yield a clear answer), so I think you’d have to add a link explaining what that is.

Comment: Why doesn't it fit the format? Please advise so I can improve question. I am referring to a front-end web project using Foundation - http://foundation.zurb.com and I am just using it as an example.

Comment: It’s not far outside of the format. However, the answer to your very generally phrased question (Should I be installing modules globally?) depends on some factors that the answerer has to assume, e.g. whether you are going to use the same installation for other projects (which both @kody and I assume you would, in this case). You could make these factors explicit when writing the question.